# Connecting to nodeJS SSL from browser with proxy

Tags: node.js, wordpress, ssl, websocket, wss

I have a wordpress site using apache and it is forwarding traffic from /server to nodeJS.  I also have a C# webGL game on the site which is connecting to the server like so..

```
    ws = new WebSocket("wss://mydomain.io:8000");
    ws.SetProxy("https://mydomain.io/server", "", "");
```

Here is how its being redirected..

```
 <Location /server>
      ProxyPass wss://mydomain.io:8000
      ProxyPassReverse wss://mydomain.io:8000
 </Location>
```

The C# game can connect well but I also need to connect to the server from the browser and I'm not sure how to do that.  Here is what I got..

```
                let socket = new WebSocket("wss://mydomain.io:8000");
                
                socket.send('username#232');
                socket.onmessage = function(e) {
                    jQuery('#timer').html(e.data);
                }
```

But that doesn't connect, I get this in the browser console..

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.

I think I need to let the socket know it needs to go through my main domain via HTTPS instead of WSS as a proxy as the C# game did but I don't know.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, here is the fix..

```
                    socket.onopen = () => socket.send('hello');
```

I can't believe I wasted a whole day on this xD